# Merging/cherry-picking between orphan branches

Tags: git, merge

I managed to get a git repo with an orphan branch. To reproduce it, you can do it like this ("subl code.txt" means editing the code file):

```
C:\g\orphanrepomerge> git init
C:\g\orphanrepomerge> subl code.txt
C:\g\orphanrepomerge> git add -A
C:\g\orphanrepomerge> git commit -m "added starting point (best fit for parent later)"
C:\g\orphanrepomerge> subl code.txt
C:\g\orphanrepomerge> git commit -am "simulate some dev in first branch"
C:\g\orphanrepomerge> subl code.txt
C:\g\orphanrepomerge> git commit -am "simulate some more dev in first branch"
C:\g\orphanrepomerge> git checkout --orphan second
C:\g\orphanrepomerge> git rm -rf .
C:\g\orphanrepomerge> md ./sub/folder | cd
C:\g\orphanrepomerge\sub\folder> subl code.txt
C:\g\orphanrepomerge\sub\folder> git add -A
C:\g\orphanrepomerge\sub\folder> git commit -m "initial copy of first branch"
C:\g\orphanrepomerge\sub\folder> subl code.txt
C:\g\orphanrepomerge\sub\folder> git commit -am "some dev originally in second"
```

So this is:

- master: initial commit => commit1 => commit2
- second: initial copy* => commit3

*...the copy is done in a subfolder!

the sample looks like this in git:

```
C:\g\orphanrepomerge> git log --graph master...second
* commit 0a3c91a4e72c331514fd68618febcf721d161a82
| Author: Fabian Wetzel
|
|     some dev originally in second
|
* commit f9f4718294258daee50bd89859e0626ddb0fad40
  Author: Fabian Wetzel

      initial copy of first branch

* commit ae53574452997a4be674d2d33e3fe1a3cb2bb3e6
| Author: Fabian Wetzel
|
|     simulate some more dev in first branch
|
* commit c32f6417cf818f11844a9ffb569232d65b2d5229
| Author: Fabian Wetzel
|
|     simulate some dev in first branch
|
* commit 1d8aace9312b5c51848c9fdadeac8cac53a4e7ad
  Author: Fabian Wetzel

      added starting point (best fit for parent later)
```

what I would like to do is cherry picking in both directions and it somehow works but the desired outcome is disappointing:

```
C:\g\orphanrepomerge> git checkout second
C:\g\orphanrepomerge> git cherry-pick c32f6417cf818f11844a9ffb569232d65b2d5229
error: could not apply c32f641... simulate some dev in first branch
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
C:\g\orphanrepomerge> dir -Recurse


    Directory: C:\g\orphanrepomerge


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----        29.06.2015     13:54            sub
-a---        29.06.2015     14:29         25 code.txt


    Directory: C:\g\orphanrepomerge\sub\folder


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        29.06.2015     13:55         30 code.txt
```

git added the original code.txt back to the root folder instead of actually merging the changes into the code.txt in the subfolder. I can understand why it does this but nevertheless it is wrong for me.

I somehow need to introduce a parent to the first commit in [second] to retroactively transform the orphan branch into a real branch, but I do not know how?!

Comment: Take a look at [graft points](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GraftPoint).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The by far easiest approach would be the usage of a [graft point](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GraftPoint).

### Explanation

So, what's a *graft point*? Using a graft point you can **fake** the ancestry of commits. This can be used for a variety of purposes, for example to remove the history of a repository prior to a specific commit.

How do we use them? You can define graft points by editing the `.git/info/grafts` file. The syntax is very straightforward, the first hash is the commit which parents you want to define and all following hashes will be it's parents. It's important that you use **full hashes**, otherwise the graft point won't work.

*Origin: Graft points were mainly introduced to smooth the transition from other VCS to git, where merges didn't contain information about the merged in branch (looking at you, older SVN versions).*

### Action

In your case you can use a graft point to connect the initial commit of your orphan branch with a parent of your choice. Here is an abstract example:

```
<initial orphan branch commit hash> <parent commit hash>
```

Using the hashes from your question this would look like this:

```
f9f4718294258daee50bd89859e0626ddb0fad40 1d8aace9312b5c51848c9fdadeac8cac53a4e7ad
```

### Make it permanent

If you want to make the change permanent, instead of relying on the graft point, you can use `git filter-branch -- --all`. From the [`filter-branch` documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch):

> This command honors `.git/info/grafts` file and refs in the `refs/replace/` namespace. If you have any grafts or replacement refs defined, running this command will make them permanent.

The `-- --all` appendix just includes all references so you don't have to specify the references manually.

**IMPORTANT**: This will make your orphan-branch history incompatible with any pushed history of the branch. Be sure to understand the implications of this.

Comment: man, you saved my day! I was literally working on this for a day and halve already! Thank you!

Comment: @fabsenet You're welcome, I'm glad to be of assistance. :)