# How to incorporate changes across branches, yet keep their commit histories independent?

Tags: git

If I do this, `master` and `other` are in the same state, but start from independent commit histories:

```
git checkout --orphan other
git add -all
git commit -m "first"
```

In my actual situation, I need this because there is an encryption step between `checkout` and `add --all`, but I will leave that aside.

If I switch back to `master` and make a new commit, how would I incorporate it into `other`, while still keeping commit histories independent?

---

In response to comments, ["faking the ancestry of commits"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31134827/9243116) does sound similar to what I'm trying to achieve but I haven't investigated its workings. In any case, 'merging commits' sounds like the opposite of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: You can't do it with the commands youve outlined. What's wrong with keeping the branches separated indefinitely and just merging other into master when you want to?

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/31134827/7160687

Comment: I use `git cherry-pick <commit_hash>` all the time for this.  Not sure if it would suffice for bulk commits though? Quoting: `Given one or more existing commits, apply the change each one introduces, recording a new commit for each. `

Comment: @johnv, I responded to your comment in the post itself.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17491404/9243116), I guess this would work, but it's tedious.

```
git checkout master
touch foo
git add foo
git commit -m "update"
git push . master:other
git reset --soft HEAD^
git add foo
git commit -m "update"
```